# OpenPop.net has added extra space into the subject of email after parsing

Tags: c#, email, openpop

ok, so i have a email with subject "Løgten VVS, Pia, Sproom på hosten. Jeg forveter det er pga den ikke kører filer ikke kommer til Sproom. Hvis det er tilfældet: start den, men I behøver ikke ringe tilbage. Pia checker selv."

and after OpenPop.net parsed the subject became "Løgten VVS, Pia, Sproom på hosten. Jeg forv eter det er pga den ikke kører filer ikke ko mmer til Sproom. Hvis det er tilfældet: star t den, men I behøver ikke ringe tilbage. Pia  checker selv."

so it has changed "forveter" to "forv eter", "kommer" to "ko mmer" and "start" to "star t", which i found it very strange.

I am using Openpop.dll version 2.0.2.340, can some1 help. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Updated OpenPop.dll to the latest version 2.0.5 have fixed this issue.